# Change CSS on different page based on condition using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my first page I have an onclick event that adds a class called Message to a form.

```
 <input type="button" onclick="isDirty()" class="btn btn-default" />

<script>
    function isDirty() {
    $('form').addClass('Message');
    }
</script>
```

Then I have an if statement that uses JQuery to check if the form has that class:

```
if ($('form').hasClass('Message')) {
    $("#commentAndFileMessage").show();
}
```

If it does, then the 'display: none;' css element of a paragraph on page 2 should change to show:

```
<p id="commentAndFileMessage">You must save the new license on the details page.</p>
```

I'm sort of new to javascript, but I'm thinking this isn't possible without a cookie or something. Does anybody know if this can work? Thanks!

Comment: By "page 2" do you mean the page redirected to by the form submit?

Comment: Avoid using `function` and `onclick` when you're using JQuery to achieve something. Use `$("button").click()` instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And not a redirect on the form submit, but a new window that pops up when a button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible without cookies, using html5 localStorage(which supports almost all modern browsers).
On first page set localStorage,code shown below

```
    function isDirty() {  
            $('form').addClass('Message');
            localStorage.setItem("form", "Message");//page1, set localstorage with form and messages as key-value pairs
        }
```

Then on page2 , get this value from localstorage

```
if(localStorage.getItem("form") == "Message")
{
$("#commentAndFileMessage").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, True you cannot do this if you're using just javascript/jquery, Use javascript cookies that should resolve your problem.

You can find full examples in link below :

[JavaScript Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)